# Prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is not well defined on $\Bbb Z_{11}\to\Bbb Z_{22}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is not well defined

The functions are from $\Bbb Z_{11}$ to $\Bbb Z_{22}$

I know i just need a counter example and I was thinking $x=-1$ and $y=3$

Comment: Do you mean not well-defined, or not injective?

Comment: And what do you mean by `Z_1_1` and `Z_2_2`?

Comment: f(x) = x^2 *is* well defined.  For any x there is only one way to interpret f(x).  Now, g(x) = y such that $y^2 = x$ is *not* well defined.

Comment: Its meant to be Z subscript 11 to 22 (as in the equivalence relations.

Comment: I don't know what those equivalence relations are. Do you mean {0}x{0} -> {0,1}x{0,1} ?

Comment: Is the problem assuming that $x = 3 \in Z_{11}$ means $x = 3 \ \text{or} \ 14 \in Z_{22}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be specified what $x$ represents.

If we are defining $f$ in such a way that it maps the equivalence class of $\overline{x}$ to the equivalence class of $\overline{x^2}$ where all possible representations of the equivalence class are allowed, then bad things can happen.

Notice that $\overline{0}=\overline{11}$ in $\Bbb Z_{11}$.  We would hope that $f(\overline{0})=f(\overline{11})$ for $f$ to be a function.

See what happens though: $f(\overline{0})=\overline{0^2}=\overline{0}$ in $\Bbb Z_{22}$, however $f(\overline{11})=\overline{11^2}=\overline{121}=\overline{11}\neq \overline{0}$ in $\Bbb Z_{22}$.

In the context of $\Bbb Z_{22}$ you have the equivalence class $\overline{0}=\{\dots,-66,-44,-22,0,22,44,66,\dots\}$ whereas $\overline{11}=\{\dots,-55,-33,-11,11,33,55,\dots\}$

Since $f$ maps two *equal* things to *nonequal* targets, $f$ is not well defined and therefore not a function.

We could make $f$ a function however by referring to elements in $\Bbb Z_{11}$ **only by their canonical representatives**, namely the unique integer $r$ in $\{0,1,2,\dots, 10\}$ such that $x\equiv r\pmod{11}$.

In this case, there is absolutely no ambiguity as there is *only one way to represent an element of* $\Bbb Z_{11}$ and $f$ will in fact be a function.